# C# entity code first FULL TEXT INDEX Data Annotation

Tags: c#, indexing, entity, code-first

With EF6 Code first, How can I declare with Data Annotation (not fluent) a **FULL TEXT INDEX** on name property :

```
public class Picture
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

it's should looks like to : ?

```
public class Picture
{
    [Index("IX_Picture_Name ") ?? ]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks

**UPDATE:**
So if is not possible with data annotation, maybe with fluent ?

Comment: I don't think you can, also not sure you could query using a fulltext index with EF either.

Comment: @DavidG Yes I think it's, I try to do this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616304/entity-framework-code-first-and-full-text-search/19644900#19644900

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is NO.
Sorry for this question. After more research, I understand this kind of index is really different as classic index and can't be declared like this.

By the way, if you want to implement FTS on azure, it's recently on preview: http://azure.microsoft.com/fr-fr/documentation/articles/search-get-started/

It's a real service, much one than a simple index...