# Search keywords using EntityFramework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq, t-sql

My table NewsArticles has the following columns: Id and Text (this contains the content of news articles)

```
var keywords = new List<string>{
 "Lorem ipsum dolor",
 "elementum lacinia",
 "cursus nulla molestie",
}
```

Here's my query but it does work as expected

```
dbContext.NewsArticles.Where(article=>keywords.Contains(article.Text)).ToArray()
```

The results should be any articles that contains all words of one of the keywords regardless of word ordering

An article that has the follow would be a match
"ipsum example Lorem text dolor"

Is this possible with a single query?

If not, what would be some alternatives? a stored procedure?

Comment: No, in this way I think its not possible. Maybe you can try this dbContext.NewsArticles.Where(article=>keywords.Contains(article.Text.ToArray())) but I am not completely sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure how LINQ to EF would translate this, or if it's even efficient off the top of my head, but I think this is the correct LINQ you're looking for (your logic is off):

```
// First, put your keywords in something more LINQ-friendly
var keywordGroups = keywords.Select(k => k.Split(' ')).ToArray();

Where(article => keywordGroups.
    Any(keywordGroup => keywordGroup.
        All(keyword => article.Text.Contains(keyword))))
```

That being said, if the keyword groups were fixed I'd probably hard-code them into the query and maybe drop into SQL if EF was getting in the way.

If the keyword groups weren't fixed, I'd still drop into SQL if EF was getting in the way.

The below code shows how to dynamically construct a LINQ expression tree that hopefully does what you want:

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Sandbox
{
    public class NewsArticle
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }

    public class NewsArticleRepository
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// This demonstartes how to perform the logic with a simple LINQ query.
        /// Untetested with Linq to EF.
        /// </summary>
        public IEnumerable<NewsArticle> GetArticlesWithKeywordsUsingLinq(IQueryable<NewsArticle> articles, IEnumerable<string> keywords)
        {
            var keywordGroups = keywords.Select(k => k.Split(' ')).ToArray();

            var filteredArticles = articles.Where(article => keywordGroups.
                Any(keywordGroup => keywordGroup.
                    All(keyword => article.Text.Contains(keyword))));

            var result = filteredArticles.AsEnumerable();

            return result;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This demonstartes how to perform the logic with an expression tree;
        /// This is probably more efficient when converted to SQL.
        /// Untetested with Linq to EF.
        /// </summary>
        public IEnumerable<NewsArticle> GetArticlesWithKeywordsUsingExpressionTree(IQueryable<NewsArticle> articles, IEnumerable<string> keywords)
        {
            var keywordGroups = keywords.Select(k => k.Split(' ')).ToArray();

            var filteredArticles = articles.Where(GetWhereClauseForKeywordGroups(keywordGroups));

            var result = filteredArticles.AsEnumerable();

            return result;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This demonstartes how to perform the logic with an expression tree;
        /// This is probably even more efficient when converted to SQL because it uses a UNION instead of OR.
        /// Untetested with Linq to EF.
        /// </summary>
        public IEnumerable<NewsArticle> GetArticlesWithKeywordsUsingExpressionTreeWithUnion(IQueryable<NewsArticle> articles, IEnumerable<string> keywords)
        {
            var keywordGroups = keywords.Select(k => k.Split(' ')).ToArray();

            var filteredArticles = articles.Where(a => false);
            foreach (var keywordGroup in keywordGroups)
            {
                var articlesWithAllKeywordsInGroup = articles.Where(GetWhereClauseForKeywordGroup(keywordGroup));
                filteredArticles = filteredArticles.Union(articlesWithAllKeywordsInGroup);
            }

            var result = filteredArticles.AsEnumerable();

            return result;
        }

        private Expression<Func<NewsArticle, bool>> GetWhereClauseForKeywordGroup(string[] keywordGroup)
        {
            var containsMethod = GetContainsMethod();

            var article = Expression.Parameter(typeof(NewsArticle), "article");

            Expression containsAllKeywords = Expression.Constant(true);
            foreach (var keyword in keywordGroup)
            {
                var containsKeyword = Expression.Call(
                    Expression.Property(article, "Text"),
                    containsMethod,
                    Expression.Constant(keyword));

                containsAllKeywords = Expression.And(containsAllKeywords, containsKeyword);
            }

            var whereClause = Expression.Lambda<Func<NewsArticle, bool>>(containsAllKeywords, article);

            return whereClause;
        }

        private Expression<Func<NewsArticle, bool>> GetWhereClauseForKeywordGroups(string[][] keywordGroups)
        {
            var containsMethod = GetContainsMethod();

            var article = Expression.Parameter(typeof(NewsArticle), "article");

            Expression containsSomeKeywordGroup = Expression.Constant(false);
            foreach (var keywordGroup in keywordGroups)
            {
                Expression containsAllKeywords = Expression.Constant(true);
                foreach (var keyword in keywordGroup)
                {
                    var containsKeyword = Expression.Call(
                        Expression.Property(article, "Text"),
                        containsMethod,
                        Expression.Constant(keyword));

                    containsAllKeywords = Expression.And(containsAllKeywords, containsKeyword);
                }

                containsSomeKeywordGroup = Expression.Or(containsSomeKeywordGroup, containsAllKeywords);
            }

            var whereClause = Expression.Lambda<Func<NewsArticle, bool>>(containsSomeKeywordGroup, article);

            return whereClause;
        }

        private static MethodInfo GetContainsMethod()
        {
            var stringMethods = typeof(string).
                GetMethods(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public).ToArray();
            var containsMethods = stringMethods.Where(m => m.Name == "Contains");
            var containsMethod = containsMethods.Single();
            return containsMethod;
        }
    }

    public class Tests
    {
        private NewsArticle _requestedExample;
        private NewsArticle _missingWord;
        private NewsArticle _inOrder;
        private NewsArticle _outOfOrder;
        private IQueryable<NewsArticle> _articles;
        private List<string> _keywords;

        [SetUp]
        public void SetUp()
        {
            this._keywords = new List<string>
            {
                "Lorem ipsum dolor",
                "elementum lacinia",
                "cursus nulla molestie"
            };

            this._requestedExample = new NewsArticle
            {
                Text = "Requested Example: ipsum example Lorem text dolor"
            };
            this._missingWord = new NewsArticle
            {
                Text = "Missing word: cursus nulla"
            };
            this._inOrder = new NewsArticle
            {
                Text = "In Order: Lorem ipsum dolor"
            };
            this._outOfOrder = new NewsArticle
            {
                Text = "Out of Order: Lorem dolor ipsum"
            };

            this._articles = new[]
            {
                this._requestedExample,
                this._missingWord,
                this._inOrder,
                this._outOfOrder,
            }.AsQueryable();
        }

        [Test]
        public void GetArticlesWithKeywordsUsingLinqShouldWork()
        {
            var result = new NewsArticleRepository().GetArticlesWithKeywordsUsingLinq(this._articles, this._keywords).ToArray();

            AssertResult(result);
        }

        [Test]
        public void GetArticlesWithKeywordsUsingExpressionTreeShouldWork()
        {
            var result = new NewsArticleRepository().GetArticlesWithKeywordsUsingExpressionTree(this._articles, this._keywords).ToArray();

            AssertResult(result);
        }

        [Test]
        public void GetArticlesWithKeywordsUsingExpressionTreeWithUnionShouldWork()
        {
            var result = new NewsArticleRepository().GetArticlesWithKeywordsUsingExpressionTreeWithUnion(this._articles, this._keywords).ToArray();

            AssertResult(result);
        }

        private void AssertResult(NewsArticle[] result)
        {
            Assert.That(result.Contains(this._requestedExample), Is.True);
            Assert.That(result.Contains(this._missingWord), Is.False);
            Assert.That(result.Contains(this._inOrder), Is.True);
            Assert.That(result.Contains(this._outOfOrder), Is.True);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using .Contains, which translates to the SQL LIKE operator, will yield very poor performance.  Consider using Full-Text search.  You can read up on it here.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx

Comment: Is EF compatible with full text search?

Comment: @Jasmine: I did a quick search; [maybe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616304/entity-framework-code-first-and-full-text-search)

Comment: @Jasmine no, EF doesn't support it directly.  You would have to write a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

you can use except.

```
bool contained = !subset.Except(superset).Any();
```

so in your case it has to be something like this:

```
dbContext.NewsArticles.Where(article=>!keywords.Except(article.Text).Any()).ToArray()
```

take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/407729/determine-if-a-sequence-contains-all-elements-of-another-sequence-using-linq)